# How do I get a string from assembly register and store in a variable in C++?

Tags: c++, assembly, inline-assembly

I know that the register ECX holds a UNICODE string, which is "YODA".

I want to get the full string from the ECX register and store it in a C++ variable. Then I want to compare the variable against the string "YODA" just to confirm that it is what I expect.

I have the following code:

```
wchar_t* c;
__asm mov c, ecx

    if (wcscmp(c, L"YODA") == 0)
    {
        MessageBox(0, L"Found", L"Found", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox(0, c, L"Not Found", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
    }
```

However, it seems that it's not inserting the string properly into c.
What should I do?

Comment: `char c[5]  = {};` perhaps? And of course `std::string(c) == "YODA"`. Your code compares a pointer to `"YODA"` with c which is a different pointer, and probably not ever going to be the same.

Comment: Does `ecx` hold 0x594F4441 (or some permutation thereof) or a pointer to a string?

Comment: Yes harold it does, it point to a point in memory that has the string.

Comment: Then you need to either use `strcmp` or `std::string(c) == "YODA");` [or possibly `std::wstring` and `wstrcmp`)

Comment: I've updated my code, still not working.

Comment: @Ricky - if `ecx` holds a _pointer_ to a string, could you update your question to reflect that? Also what value does `c` have (i.e. to what address does it point) after you execute the assembly statement?

Comment: @MatsPetersson: `char c[5]` wouldn't make `c` a pointer, and the intent of the `asm mov` is to assign ECX to a pointer.

Comment: @Ricky: Try a straightforward `MessageBox(0,c,c,MB_OK)` first.

Comment: @MSalters: Correct, but the original post was made in such a way that it was not clear whether `ECX` contains the actual bytes or a pointer to it. (In fact the text still says "ECX contains the Unicode string ..." - which clearly is incorrect given the later comments)

Answer (score 2):

There's a surprising amount of issues with just a few lines of code:

- You said it's an unicode string, yet you're telling the compiler it's not. Unicode characters have type `wchar_t`, not `char`.
- ECX is usually holding `this`. I sincerely doubt your information on the contents of your registers.
- That's not how you compare strings in C++. You use `strcmp` and co. In particular you need `wcscmp`. Also that's not how you write `YODA` as an unicode string, you want `L"YODA"`.

Comment: I've updated my code, still doesn't run as expected.

Comment: That means nothing to me. Especially since I already said that's most likely not what you have at ECX.

Comment: I've mentioned above that ECX points to a location in memory that stores the unicode value YODA....

Comment: Instead of repeating yourself, you could show a memory dump along with your registers at the point where you call your `__asm` instruction. You could show the contents of `c` after the assignment, and a memory dump of the location in question. "Code is not working" and "I already said ECX points at a string" are both useless noise at best, and childish tantrums at worst.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
WCHAR c[256];
__asm 
{
 [ecx], ecx
mov [c], ecx
```

}

```
 if (lstrcmp(c, L"this" == 0)
          //your code here
```